# How to write array in SOAP UI

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I need to send array of object using SOAP UI. How to write it in SOAP UI ?

if using Java this is my code

```
Map<String, Object> travellerArray = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Object> adult = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> child = null;
ArrayList<Object> infant = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, String> detailAdult = new HashMap<>();
detailAdult.put("adult_name", "Adult1");
detailAdult.put("adult_id", "id1");
detailAdult.put("adult_date_of_birth", "2000-01-01");
detailAdult.put("adult_phone", "phone1");

adult.add(detailAdult);

Map<String, String> detailInfant = new HashMap<>();
detailInfant.put("infant_name", "Infant");
detailInfant.put("infant_date_of_birth", "2003-01-01");

infant.add(detailInfant);

travellerArray.put("adult", adult);
travellerArray.put("child", child);
travellerArray.put("infant", infant);
```

I already try write like this

```
<travellerArray xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Array[3]">
    <adult xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:anyType[1]">
        <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Array[4]">
            <adult_name>Adult1</adult_name>
            <adult_id>id1</adult_id>
            <adult_date_of_birth>2000-01-01</adult_date_of_birth>
            <adult_phone>123</adult_phone>
        </item>
    </adult>
    <child xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="unnamed_struct_use_soapval[0]">
    </child>
    <infant xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="unnamed_struct_use_soapval[0]">
        <item xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Array[2]">
            <infant_name>Adult1</infant_name>
            <infant_date_of_birth>2003-01-01</adult_date_of_birth>
        </item>
    </infant>
</travellerArray>
```

But the server always said "Invalid data". Anyone can tell me how to write / which part i do it wrong?

Comment: So what does the WSDL say about the payload?

Comment: ```
<operation name="travelBook">
<documentation>Travel Book</documentation>
<input message="tns:bookRequest"/>
<output message="tns:bookResponse"/>
</operation>
```
<message name="bookRequest">
<part name="travellerArray" type="xsd:Array"/>
</message>
<message name="bookResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:Array"/>
</message>

Comment: If you take the request example from above, and copy/paste it into the request window in a Soap Request teststep, and then try to validate it. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after few try i found this is the answer

This is example for single array

```
<travellerArray>
<adult>
<item>
<title>Mr</title>
<first_name>First</first_name>
<last_name>Last</last_name>
</item>
</adult>
</travellerArray>
```

For 2 or more array

```
<travellerArray>
<adult>
<title>Mr</title>
<first_name>First</first_name>
<last_name>Last</last_name>
</adult>
<adult>
<title>Mr</title>
<first_name>First2</first_name>
<last_name>Last2</last_name>
</adult>
</travellerArray>
```

The reason why server give "invalid data". That they give me wrong message, i too many send the incorrect format. So they ban me, because of that the return message always "invalid data".